# Can I use the HTML5 API to validate a form field value dynamically against a list of allowed values?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Can I use the HTML5 API to validate a form field value dynamically against a list of allowed values? If so, can someone show me how, or provide links to any articles that demonstrate this.

Comment: Why not just use a `select` field...?

Comment: The input field is a comma seperated list of recipients containing group names and/or email addresses. I realise now that because this is a complex field with more than one validation my question doesn't really makes sense. I think I need to parse the list and validate the individual parts seperately in js code and then set a custom validation error message if I determine the field has errors. How do I set the status of the field as invalid, though, so that the browser will highlight it and show the message?

Comment: I should have titled the post "Can I use the HTML5 API to validate a form field dynamically" since the list of groups will need to be retrieved from the  server as it is subject to change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datalist with required attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser" required>
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp